# Javascript separate string by line pushing into array

Tags: javascript

I have a string with multiple lines.

```
one
two
three
```

I need to add them to an array separated by line

How can I do that?

Comment: [String.prototype.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Comment: Post more of the code you already have.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: use split str.split(" ")

Comment: If I have the string on multiple words that are in a different line each and I have myArray = []; How do I put them in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `string.split` to cut your string at newlines. You can add a `Array.filter` to remove the empty lines.

`Filter` will loop at every `string` and create a new array. If the `string` is empty it will not push it to the new array.

```js
const str = `one
two

three`;

const ret = str.split('\n').filter(x => x.length);

console.log(str);
console.log(ret);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) such as below

```
const someString = `one
two
three`;

const myArray = someString.split('\n');

console.log(myArray);
```